# An idiom for "a hidden clue that will unravel a mystery"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a good idiom to express the idea of a clue or a key which if found can unravel or solve a mystery or greater problem.
A lynchpin to a mystery or diagnosis with implications of it being hidden or obscured

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Could you tell us what idioms you've considered and rejected, and why you've rejected them? Could you tell us what research you've done?

Comment: [***Rosetta Stone***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone) is often used figuratively. But ***key*** is a far more common metaphor for this context anyway. Note that figurative ***lynchpin*** means *a person or thing ***vital*** to an enterprise or organization*, which isn't at all the same thing as "key which unlocks a mystery".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: +1 for the "key of the mistery".

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options with the idiomatic expressions in bold:

> Once we found out that John Doe's fingerprints were on the gun, we knew we had [**the last piece to the puzzle**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-piece-of-the-puzzle-jigsaw). Today, he was found guilty.
>
> John Doe's fingerprints were on the gun, and that [**did the trick**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+the+trick). Today, he was found guilty.
>
> John Doe's fingerprints were on the gun, and that [**sealed the deal**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/seal-the-deal). Today, he was found guilty.
>
> John Doe's fingerprints were on the gun, and that **unraveled the knot**. Today, he was found guilty.

This one is clunky with the gun example I've been using, so I'll change it to knife.

> John Doe's fingerprints were on the knife, and that was our [**smoking gun**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+smoking+gun). Today, he was found guilty.

Comment: Are you actually quoting from some site? Or are these your own examples? :)

Comment: These are just examples that came to mind. I did in fact try to search for idioms that would fit this question, but I found it remarkably difficult to come up with phrasing for such a query, and such efforts were unfruitful. These examples are my own. I just used quote formatting to improve the aesthetics of the answer.

Comment: You can have your own styles, but it is important to add references, and I've added some for you. :)

Comment: This is me being pedantic, but only because I'm trying to understand what you're suggesting, not because this is personal. If by citing references you mean providing external links for the user's benefit such that he/she can find out more information about the topics I presented, I'm fine with that. But if you're arbitrarily adding links to suggest/guess where I got the information from (my own knowledge of the English language), that doesn't make sense.

Comment: +1 For further reading, and for proof that these are not made-up expressions by you. :)

Comment: No problem, just wanted to clarify. Thanks for the additions.

Comment: I don't think the references add much, particularly since the examples aren't all that apt. The *missing piece of the puzzle* and a *smoking gun* aren't hidden at all: the former's shape per force is obvious; the latter's signal is likewise. Things that *do the trick* or *seal the deal* needn't be hidden and they needn't solve a mystery. If I offer another $100K to seal the deal, is the extra money not an obvious and unmysterious reason for the conclusion of the transaction? it's time and patience that *unravel a knot*. Which you do to solve a problem, not necessarily a mystery.

Comment: I think ***missing** piece of the puzzle* could work. Once you've found that, all the rest of the pieces fall into place.

Comment: @deadrat Couldn't it be true that the shape of the missing piece of the puzzle is obvious only after you've found it? Couldn't it be the key you were searching for?

Comment: I've always thought of it like this: http://www.laurenvaknine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/missing.jpg with the definite article. I think that's what asOl had in mind with *last*. But the google shows that *a missing piece* is a common usage (about 20% that of *the missing piece*). So I think you're right.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for a ***missing link*** (excuse the pun)!

**[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/missing%20link)**:

> **missing link**
>   *noun*
>
> something that **you do not have** and that you need to complete a
>   series or **to solve a problem**
>
> Police are hopeful that the new evidence will provide the missing
>   links needed to solve the crime.
>
> scientists searching for the missing link

Comment: Aside from the unfortunate collision with paleontology of primates, a missing link is gone, not hidden.